# Search data from different tables using SQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

i have 4 database tables (office, facility, course, treatment) the id in office table acts as office id in all other 3 tables.

office

```
id  name   address    phoneno  city
1    O1    address1    12      city1
2    O2    address2    34      city2
3    O3    address2    45      city3
```

facility

```
id   office_facility   office_id
1       F1              1
2       F2              1
3       F3              2
```

Course

```
id   office_course   office_id
1       C1              1
2       C2              2
3       C3              3
```

Treatment

```
id    office_treatment  office_id
1        T1               1
2        T2               2
3        T3               2
```

i am trying to conduct a search for office on the basis of facility, course and treatment. the search code that i have worked works when there is only one table and the criteria of search is part of that same table, however this case is different.

code for search is

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['city']);

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE city LIKE '%$city%'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "Office name: " . $row["office_name"]. " - Location: " . $row["office_address"]. " " . $row["office_city"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Would appreciate if anyone could tell me how i can search offices from these tables

Comment: Basically what is your need?

Comment: @Miya G i wish to search for offices on the basis of facility, course and treatment

Comment: @jane: But what does this mean? You want to select offices and limit the results such that a certain facility, course and treatment must exist for that office? Or what else?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to perform a complex SQL query against database, concatenating all the conditions you have:

```
SELECT address FROM office
  JOIN facility ON (facility.office_id = office.id)
  JOIN course ON (course.office_id = office.id)
  JOIN treatment ON (treatment.office_id = office.id)
WHERE city LIKE %...% 
  AND office_facility LIKE %...%
  AND office_course LIKE %...%
  AND office_treatment LIKE %...%
```

The values for `LIKE` as well as boolean logic on `AND`/`OR` is now up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use union for that

```
select A.ID,(SELECT B.Name from office B where A.ID=B.ID) as Name from (

select id  from office where <Your Office Table filter Criteria>

UNION 

select office_id from facility where <Your facility Table filter Criteria>

UNION 

select office_id from Course where <Your Course Table filter Criteria>

UNION 

select office_id from Treatment where <Your Treatment Table filter Criteria>
)A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join query. Actually you haven't clarify that what is you need so I ma trying to give you same basic(global) example

```
"select from table_name as td 
left join anoather_table as anoth on td.common_column = anoth.commoncolun whare td.condition_columh= condition"
```